# Getting a JObject by a property value

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am building a contact management system. Each contact can relate to the business in one of three ways: client, service provider, and third party.

I have a JSON file containing the relation types and their importance to the business (so I could priorities messages, for example):

```
{
    "Relations": [
        {
            "Name": "Client",
            "Importance": 1
        },
        {
            "Name": "Service Provider",
            "Importance": 2
        },
        {
            "Name": "ThirdParty",
            "Importance": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a method that gets the name of the relation and retrieves a `JObject` containing the JSON representing this relation, using Json.NET:

```
private JObject GetRelationJSON(string relationName)
{
    string jString = File.ReadAllText("relations.json");
    JObject relationsJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jString);

    // I am specifically not sure about this line
    return (JObject)(relationsJSON["Relations"].Where(r => ((string)r["Name"]).Equals(relationName)).ToList()[0]);
}
```

Note that I am not allowed to deserialize the JSON into POCO classes.

How can I improve this code? Thanks!

Comment: _I am not allowed to deserialize the JSON into POCO classes._ - this is a very strange limitation. Could you explain why?

Comment: @t3chb0t - Yes! My senior has taken the decision that all the JSON handling in our project should be dynamic, and so without deserialization into POCO classes, even when a dynamic approach is not really required (for consistency reasons). I happen to disagree with this approach, but I am still bound to it. :)

Comment: Oh boy, poor you having such a senior :-\ sacrificing type safety for questionable consistency reasons... people have ideas, lol - although some companies happen to not like `var` :-| another _great_ idea.

Comment: I'd be great if you could post the real code - do not remove any parts even if you think it's irrelevant - it is not - currently the `jObject` variable is not defined :(

Comment: @t3chb0t - edited the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Not being able to use POCO is tough enough so don't make your life even harder with the line you're asking about. It's much easier to query it with [`JsonPath`](https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/api/endpoint/jsonpath.html) like that:

```
return (JObject)relationsJSON.SelectToken($"$.Relations[?(@.Name=='{relationName}')]");
```

and since you are not using POCO then you don't have to deserialize it. It's ok when you just let json.net parse it with `JToken` and then do the `JsonPath` thing:

```
JToken.Parse(json).SelectToken(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

As t3chb0t described in his [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/206730/150696), you just need a JToken to work with Linq or SelectToken.

```
var relationsJSON = JToken.Parse(jString);
```

And instead of using Where, you could simplify you Linq Expression by using FirstOrDefault.

```
 return (JObject)(relationsJSON["Relations"].FirstOrDefault(q => (string)q["Name"] == relationName));
```

This way, then method returns null, if relationsJSON doesn't contain a relation matching the relationName.